# AWS JavaScript s3Client image uploads cutting off

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-js

I have an image upload service which I'm working on switching over to use Linode Cloud Storage. This is an S3-compatible storage service, so I can make uploads using the AWS JavaScript SDK. Everything is working except that my uploaded images are getting cut off abruptly.

Here's my code:

```js
const s3 = new S3Client({
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: [ACCESS_KEY],
        secretAccessKey: [SECRET_KEY]
    },
    region: [REGION],
    endpoint: [ENDPOINT]
});

function uploadFile(fileName, filePath) {
    return s3.send(new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        ContentType: mime.getType(filePath),
        ContentLength: fs.statSync(filePath).size,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }));
}
```

The above code results in an image like this:
[image: cut off image]

Very small images work, but anything over a few megabytes gets this issue. Should I be using a different method to stream the file rather than `fs.createReadStream()`?

Comment: The code seems OK - are you sure you have the entire file locally when you're starting the upload? Try printing the `fs.statSync(filePath).size` value, see if it looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Okay tricky one but I finally found my answer.

First I had to switch my code to use `Body: fs.readFileSync(filePath)` in order to get an actual error to throw in the s3Client during upload. That bit seems like a problem with the AWS SDK's s3Client failing to notice that the upload went wrong.

The error was `[ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`, and Googling that brought me to [this issue in the Linode forums](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/21180/object-storage-upload-err_stream_write_after_end-write-after-end).

Turns out this is a bug in Linode Cloud Storage where it responds with `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` *multiple* times, causing s3Client to stream the upload more than once (or maybe split the upload stream into chunks? Not sure on the exact details of what s3Client is doing). The final uploaded image is incomplete.

This is the second LCS bug I've run into. I'll likely be using a different service to avoid further problems. Arguably the s3Client should be more resilient to this, but Linode's clearly doing something wrong here since other services don't see this problem. I tried a quick switch to Backblaze B2 and my code works perfectly there.